# How to center graphic horizontally in table cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, center

I want to center my graphic horizontally, which I include in my table cell. It is centered vertically, but I also want it centered horizontally. What can I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage, twoside]{article}

% overfull, underfull 
\hbadness=\maxdimen
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\vfuzz=30pt
\hfuzz=30pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary} % Dla bardziej zaawansowanych tabel. Zawija automatycznie tekst
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[OT4]{polski} % pakiet języka polskiego
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %pakiet do przesuwania grafiki prawo/lewo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pakiet do grafiki
%\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz} %pakiet do przekreślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %pakiet do kolorowania tablicy
\usepackage[ showframe, margin = 2cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\makeatletter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref} % %pakiet do wstawiania linków z kolorem
\usepackage{caption}    %for going to the top of an image when a figure reference is clicked
\usepackage[text= black, background = white , arrow = gray ]{callouts} % Dodawanie odnośników na figures - parametry 
\usepackage{tikz} % Rysowanie strzałek, odnośników na figures
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
%\usepackage{parskip} parskip = 1pt
\usepackage{multirow} % Biblioteka dla scalania wierszy tabel
%\usepackage{pbox} % Biblioteka dla dodwania nowych linii, bez dodawania nowego wiersza w tabeli 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage{calc}% Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Biblioteka dla przesuwania obrazków w prawą stronę
\usepackage{enumitem} % Biblioteka dla numeracji poprzedzonej literą
\usepackage{listliketab} % Biblioteka, dzięki której można wprowadzać numerację w tabeli
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tasks,blindtext}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage} % Zaczynanie rozdziału zawsze od nowej strony
\usepackage{float} % Pakiet używany w celu wymuszenia pozycjonowania tabeli/zdjęcia w miejscu wywołania
\restylefloat{table} % -||-
\usepackage{mdwlist} % pozwala na zawieszanie (suspend) i wznawianie numerowania (resume)
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Usunięcie wcięć w nowych akapitach
\usepackage{ragged2e} % bibioteka, która pozwala na wprowadzania wyrówanania do prawej i lewej 
\usepackage{tabularray} % Pakiet do tabel. M.in. do centrowania zdjęć 

\begin{table}[H]
\centering

    \begin{tabularx}{17cm}{|X|>{\columncolor{yellow}}m{12cm}|}
    \hline
     \multirow[c]{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{symbol2.png}} & \textbf{Ważne!} \\
    & \begin{itemize}
        \item Na maszynie może pracować wyłącznie przeszkolony i poinstruowany personel.
        \item Należy jasno określić kompetencje personelu dotyczące obsługi, konserwacji i naprawy.
    \end{itemize}\\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your result? I don't have your image, but if I add a dummy image, e.g. `example-image`, it looks horizontally centred. Or do you maybe want to center it vertically, e.g. that the space above and below the image is the same?

Comment: are you sure you want  `\hbadness=\maxdimen \vbadness=\maxdimen`  which means "I don't care how bad the output is" why ask about finer points like alignment in that case?

Comment: Unrelated. `hyperref` should be the one of the last packages to load with exception to `cleveref` which should be loaded after `hyperref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already loading the `tabularray` package, you could use it to center your image both vertically and horizontally:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage, twoside]{article}

% overfull, underfull 
\hbadness=\maxdimen
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\vfuzz=30pt
\hfuzz=30pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary} % Dla bardziej zaawansowanych tabel. Zawija automatycznie tekst
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[OT4]{polski} % pakiet języka polskiego
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pakiet do grafiki
%\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz} %pakiet do przekreślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %pakiet do kolorowania tablicy
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %pakiet do przesuwania grafiki prawo/lewo
\usepackage[ showframe, margin = 2cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\makeatletter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref} % %pakiet do wstawiania linków z kolorem
\usepackage{caption}    %for going to the top of an image when a figure reference is clicked
\usepackage[text= black, background = white , arrow = gray ]{callouts} % Dodawanie odnośników na figures - parametry 
\usepackage{tikz} % Rysowanie strzałek, odnośników na figures
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
%\usepackage{parskip} parskip = 1pt
\usepackage{multirow} % Biblioteka dla scalania wierszy tabel
%\usepackage{pbox} % Biblioteka dla dodwania nowych linii, bez dodawania nowego wiersza w tabeli 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage{calc}% Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Biblioteka dla przesuwania obrazków w prawą stronę
\usepackage{enumitem} % Biblioteka dla numeracji poprzedzonej literą
\usepackage{listliketab} % Biblioteka, dzięki której można wprowadzać numerację w tabeli
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tasks,blindtext}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage} % Zaczynanie rozdziału zawsze od nowej strony
\usepackage{float} % Pakiet używany w celu wymuszenia pozycjonowania tabeli/zdjęcia w miejscu wywołania
\restylefloat{table} % -||-
\usepackage{mdwlist} % pozwala na zawieszanie (suspend) i wznawianie numerowania (resume)
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Usunięcie wcięć w nowych akapitach
\usepackage{ragged2e} % bibioteka, która pozwala na wprowadzania wyrówanania do prawej i lewej 
\usepackage{tabularray} % Pakiet do tabel. M.in. do centrowania zdjęć 

 \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering

    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={|X|Q[12cm,yellow,valign=m]|},
      measure=vbox
    }
    \hline
    \SetCell[r=2]{halign=c} \includegraphics[valign=m,width=4cm]{example-image-duck} & \textbf{Ważne!} \\
    & \vspace*{-\baselineskip} \begin{itemize}
        \item Na maszynie może pracować wyłącznie przeszkolony i poinstruowany personel.
        \item Należy jasno określić kompetencje personelu dotyczące obsługi, konserwacji i naprawy.
    \end{itemize}\\ \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the error: "Option clash for package xcolor.". I have changed `[table]{xcolor}` to `colortbl` and your code seems to work.

Comment: @Celdor That's strange! I don't get an error with up-to-date texlive2022.

Comment: Document compiled with `pdflatex` is fine but `lualatex` causes the error: [link to overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hrnyzzsxrngg).

Comment: Seems that in lualatex one needs to load adjustbox after xcolor `% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
`

Comment: (... and it worked fine up until texlive2015 but started failing in texlive2016)

Comment: I haven't really been using latex then. Nice work you have chased that :p  Besdies, the OP's preamble is a little messy, e.g. `adjustbox` is loaded twice.

Comment: ... and it seems to work if one installs https://github.com/MartinScharrer/adjustbox/blob/main/tc-luatex.def

Comment: (I opened an issue about this at https://github.com/MartinScharrer/adjustbox/issues/1 -- let's see if this is by design or a bug)